# What is the difference between the two queries in sql server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

First query:

```
SELECT TOP (100) * 
FROM tblAppGain
```

Second query:

```
SELECT TOP (100) percent * 
FROM tblAppGain
```

Comment: Ever tried to read the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

`TOP` Limits the rows returned in a query result set to a specified number of rows or percentage of rows in SQL Server 2017. When TOP is used in conjunction with the ORDER BY clause, the result set is limited to the first N number of ordered rows; otherwise, it returns the first N number of rows in an undefined order

PERCENT
Indicates that the query returns only the first expression percent of rows from the result set. Fractional values are rounded up to the next integer value.

[see Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 1):

TOP(n) , given you first n matching rows with your criteria

if you pass [optional] percent like TOP(n) percent , will return n% of matching rows.

in your case

> Select top (100) * from tblAppGain

will return top 100 records from the table (you have not specified any criteria [where...] so first 100 records will be returned in same order they were entered)

> SELECT TOP (100) percent * FROM tblAppGain

will return 100% rows of table. and this is same as

> SELECT * FROM tblAppGain;

(which i believe is a deadly query)

try reading before asking, that was super simple google search

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: `so first 100 records will be returned in same order they were entered`. No, they will not be. The first 100 records will be returned in the order the query optimizer chooses them. They may or may not be in the same order every time. Tables are stored as _unordered_ sets. Order is only guaranteed if an `ORDER BY` clause is applied to the `SELECT` statement. It's not particularly relevant in response to this question, but it's very relevant when working with live data.